# Using multiple operators with operator overloading gives strange error

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a single class called FloatTensor. I have overloaded operators for + and * in that. Here is the code.

```
class FloatTensor {
    public:
    float val; // value of tensor 
    float grad; // value of grad
    Operation *frontOp =NULL, *backOp =NULL;
    FloatTensor* two;
    FloatTensor() {
        // default
    }

    FloatTensor(float val) {
        this->val = val;
    }

    FloatTensor(float val, Operation* op) {
        this->val = val;
        this->backOp = op;
    }

    void backward(float grad) {
        this->grad = grad;
        if(this->backOp != NULL) {
            this->backOp->backward(grad);
        }
    }
    FloatTensor exp() {
        this->frontOp = new ExponentOperation(this);
        return this->frontOp->compute();
    }

    FloatTensor operator * (FloatTensor &two) { 

        this->frontOp = new MultiplyOperation(this, &two);
        return this->frontOp->compute();
    }

    FloatTensor operator + (FloatTensor &two) { 
        this->frontOp = new AddOperation(this, &two);
        return this->frontOp->compute();
    }

    FloatTensor operator / (FloatTensor &two) { 

        this->frontOp = new DivideOperation(this, &two);
        return this->frontOp->compute();
    }

};
```

IN my main function when I try simple overloading, things work great

```
int main() {

    // X 
    FloatTensor x1(200); // heap declaration
    FloatTensor x2(300);

    // Weights
    FloatTensor w1(222);
    FloatTensor w2(907);

    FloatTensor temp = (x1*w1);

}
```

However when I try to overload this formula with more operators like this

```
int main() {

    // X 
    FloatTensor x1(200); // heap declaration
    FloatTensor x2(300);

    // Weights
    FloatTensor w1(222);
    FloatTensor w2(907);

    FloatTensor temp = (x1*w1) + (x2*w2);

}
```

I get this error:

```
no operator "+" matches these operands -- operand types are: FloatTensor + FloatTensor
```

I would be very grateful if someone can explain why this is happening. I observed that this works:

```
x1*w1*x2*x1;
x1*w1 + x2;
```

But `x1*w1 + x2*w2` does not.

Very strange..

Comment: What is the reason for `this->two = &two`? Why use a pointer? Will this pointer be stored by e.g. the `DivideOperation` objects and used much later (when the object they point to have gone out of scope or is destructed)? And why pointers for `frontOp`? That dynamic allocation looks like a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, the ```this->two = two``` is not required. I'll remove that, I'm using pointers for ```frontOp``` as I need to store a reference to the operation that a floatTensor goes through. This information will be used much later. Adding the const in front of FloatTensor two in function header is not an option as the pointer can be changed later.

Answer (score 3):

Your operators accept a non-`const` lvalue reference as an argument. Temporaries do not bind to non-`const` lvalue references. To accept temporaries, use:

```
FloatTensor operator + (const FloatTensor &two)
```

Comment: I can't let it be const as the value of two can be changed later on. Is there any way around this, while keeping two non const. Or keeping it const only for temporaries and not for say ``` x1*w1```

Comment: You can provide a non-`const` overload for non-temporaries.